# Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.gridunity.core.bean.model.CommunicationBean

Tags: java, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

My Dao looks like this:

```
package com.gridunity.core.persistence.dao;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.xxxx.core.bean.model.CommunicationInstanceBean;

@Repository
@Component
public class CommunicationInstanceDao extends JdbcDaoSupport {

@Autowired
public void setJT(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
     setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
}

public CommunicationInstanceBean findOne(int id) {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM CommunicationInstance WHERE id = ?";
    return (CommunicationInstanceBean)getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<CommunicationInstanceBean>(CommunicationInstanceBean.class), id);

}
}
```

I keep getting this error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.gridunity.core.bean.model.CommunicationBean
```

I have checked the DB, and there is only one row with the id sent in. I have tried both `.query()` and `.queryForObject()` but both throw the same error.

If I "know" there is only one row (ie, unique constraint on the db) how do I force the template to not return and array?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? [`<T> java.util.List<T> query(java.lang.String sql, RowMapper<T> rowMapper)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-): The return value is a **`List`**.

Comment: Did you read the question where I pointed out that I also tried queryForObject where the return type (where according to do the documentation that I obliviously did not read)  returns <T> T

Comment: `queryForObject` will **not** cause exception about casting `ArrayList`, so you're mistaken. Perhaps you were reading the old log entries from your earlier attempt. Try again.

Comment: Oops, sorry, you're right, and you're so very very wrong. You're right that changing *that* call to `queryForObject` will not fix the issue, because you're wrong about where the error occurs. Error says *"cannot be cast to **`CommunicationBean`**"*, but that line of code is casting to **`CommunicationInstanceBean`**. Your error is elsewhere, in code you haven't shared!!! --- Sorry, we should have forced you to show us the **full stacktrace** which would have shown this, because it shows the exactly line number of the statement causing the error, and it's not *that* statement.

Comment: @Andreas,  you are completely correct.  I the error was elsewhere where an entire stack trace would have made the answer far more obvious.  My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `SELECT` statement will only return one row (fair assumption with `id = ?`), use
[`<T> T queryForObject(String sql, RowMapper<T> rowMapper, Object... args)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-java.lang.Object...-)
instead of
[`<T> List<T> query(String sql, RowMapper<T> rowMapper, Object... args)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-java.lang.Object...-)

You also won't need a cast at all:

```
public CommunicationInstanceBean findOne(int id) {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM CommunicationInstance WHERE id = ?";
    return getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(
              sql,
              new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(CommunicationInstanceBean.class),
              id);
}
```

Comment: Is there a general rule of thumb when and when not to add the class name to to the BeanPropertyRowMapper<> ?

Comment: @mmaceachran If the compiler can infer it, you can omit it. If you use a good IDE, you can enable a warning message for when you give it where it's not needed. E.g. in Eclipse it's called "Unnecessary type parameter" or something like that. If you don't use a good IDE, you should, but otherwise try without, and add it is compiler complains. In this case the type parameter can be derived from the actual parameter (`CommunicationInstanceBean.class`).

Answer (score 0):

return getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(CommunicationInstanceBean.class), id);

Comment: Unnecessary cast.